Prometheus Alertmanager not triggering MySQL/Nginx PID alert using Telegraf exporter procstat metric
Prometheus 2.39.0
Alertmanager 0.24.0
Telegraf 1.20.2

I'm trying to setup an alert to check if MySQL/Nginx are running or not in a remote host.
I've setup 2 Prometheus jobs
For MySQL
 - job_name: "gm_mysql_pid"
    scheme: "https"
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          [
            "host1.com:9273",
          ]

and for Nginx
  - job_name: "gm_telegraf_exporter"
    scheme: "https"
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          [
            "host1.com:9273",
          ]

Alertmanager configuration
route:
  group_by: ["alertname", "group", "instance"]
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 120h
  receiver: devops-team
  routes:
    - match:
        group: gm_telegraf_exporter
      continue: true
      receiver: prometheus-receiver
receivers:
 - name: "prometheus-receiver"
    slack_configs:
      - api_url: https://hooks.slack.com/xxx
        channel: "alerts-prometheus"
        send_resolved: true
        title: '{{ template "custom_title" . }}'
        text: '{{ template "custom_slack_message" . }}'

Alert rules configuration
MySQL
  - alert: gm_mysql_pid
    expr: procstat_lookup_pid_count{job="gm_mysql_pid",pid_finder="",pidfile="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid"} <= 0
    labels:
      group: "gm_mysql_pid"
    annotations:
      identifier: "Host: {{$labels.host}}"
      description: "Trigger: MySQL service is down!"

Nginx
  - alert: gm_nginx_pid
    expr: procstat_lookup_pid_count{job="gm_telegraf_exporter",pid_finder="",pidfile="/var/run/nginx.pid"} <= 0
    labels:
      group: "gm_telegraf_exporter"
    annotations:
      identifier: "Host: {{$labels.host}}"
      description: "Trigger: Nginx service is down!"

Looking into Telegraf metrics I see both metrics:
procstat_lookup_pid_count{host="host1.com",pid_finder="pgrep",pidfile="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid",result="success"} 1
procstat_lookup_pid_count{host="host1.com",pid_finder="pgrep",pidfile="/var/run/nginx.pid",result="success"} 1

The issue is that if I stop both services (MySQL and Nginx) the Alertmanager alert is not being triggered, even if metrics show that both services are down...
procstat_lookup_pid_count{host="host1.com",pid_finder="pgrep",pidfile="",result="lookup_error"} 0

Am I missing something?

If setup is pretty much the same, why do you think both monitored services deserve being mentioned? And from focus perspective, it would be great if if you specify if alert rule is not triggered or alert notification. And depending on that - remove unrelated bloat.

Found out that the issue was caused by the Telegraf version running on the server.
The expression is running fine with version 1.8 but not with version 1.25.
Downgrading to ver. 1.8 solved the issue!
